# How to pass bind variable as IN OUT parameter in PLSQL procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, rest, bind-variables

> I want to use 1st parameter of my procedure **EMP_ID** as **IN OUT** parameter. Originally it's **IN** parameter and this procedure is working fine, but as the last line concern

`htp.p('Inserted for Employee-id '||EMP_ID);`

I want to use this line in anonymous block and most importantly it should be a bind variable because I am creating the **REST API** in which user will only enter values and it will be taken as bind variable in **oracle Apex** and the below procedure is working fine with respect of **IN** parameter.

```
create or replace procedure att_time_ins (EMP_ID in  varchar2, ORG_ID in number,V_TIME_STATUS in number) is
  BEGIN
INSERT INTO TIME_ATTENDANCE_POOL
(EMPLOYEE_ID, ATTENDANCE_DATE,TIME_HOURS,TIME_MINUTES,TIME_STATUS,LOCATION_ID,ORG_ID,PREPARED_ON )  
VALUES  
(EMP_ID, to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY'),to_char(sysdate,'HH24') ,to_char(sysdate,'MI'),V_TIME_STATUS,null,ORG_ID,
to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') );   
COMMIT;

time_management.create_attendance_sheet(v_org_id => ORG_ID,
                                          v_employee_id => EMP_ID,
                                          target_date =>  to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY'));
 htp.p('Inserted for Employee-id '||EMP_ID);



end att_time_ins;
```

I am calling my procedure in this way

```
begin
 
  att_time_ins(:employee_id,:org_id,:time_status);
 
end;
```

**Please help me to modify this stuff according to IN OUT Parameter i.e Employee_id should be IN OUT parameter**. There is no proper documentation regarding passing bind variables as in out prameter in PLSQL Block.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do anything differently in the call, once you've changed the procedure from `EMP_ID in varchar2` to `EMP_ID in out varchar2`? I don't understand why you need it to be in/out as you aren't changing the value within the procedure. It's unclear what actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Within a procedure ,Oracle or User written, all formal parameters are **always** generated as bound variables by the compiler.  The formal parameters for your procedure includes EMP_ID. So it is a bound variable. But beyond that your statement does NOT use it as an out. In a procedure an in out parameter may be used as either a left or right operand in assignment, ie you can change it's value; your desired statement does not change the value so it not not an OUT. Note: a variable used IN OUT( or OUT) ) in not the same as output.  Your procedure is working - don't change anything.

Comment: But do change `to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY')`. You should not call `to_date` with something that is *already* a date. When to you that you are implicitly converting `sysdate` to a string using NLS settings. Someone else calling your procedure from a session with different settings will get different behaviour, and quite likely an error. If the intention is to 'remove' the time then use `trunc(sysdate)` instead, which by default truncates the time to midnight. (You can't have a date without a time, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have a procedure named `PR_PROC`, you can use `VARIABLE` statement for passing `IN OUT` or `OUT` kind of variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_PROC (EMP_NAME   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                     EMP_ID     IN OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EMP_NAME||EMP_ID);

END;
   
VARIABLE KURSOR VARCHAR2
BEGIN
 :KURSOR:='4';
 PR_PROC('SENIOR',:KURSOR);
END;
```

Note: If you are using TOAD Editor you can press F5 to make it work.

[Oracle VARIABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12050.htm)